# W3schools CSS Contact Form merging with another div

Tags: html, css

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Please open this in full screen</p>
<form class="w3-container w3-half">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border"/><br/>
<input type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black"/>
</form>
<p class="w3-padding w3-center w3-card-4">© Copyright 123456789. All rights Reserved.</p>
```

As you seen that the form is merging in the copyright bar. How to prevent this merging purely using w3-css.
I want the form not to merge in the copyright bar.
And display form above the copyright bar separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just an wild idea, but try `w3-container` instead of `w3-padding`...

### Edit

As other comment states, `w3-half` contains `float`. So your footer should contain `clear`...

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Please open this in full screen</p>
<form class="w3-container w3-half">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border"/><br/>
<input type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black"/>
</form>
<p class="w3-padding w3-center w3-card-4" style="clear: both;">© Copyright 123456789. All rights Reserved.</p>
```

Comment: I also need padding for the div

Answer (score 1):

The `w3-half` class have `float: left; width: 49.99999%;`, if you don´t need two columns just remove it.

```
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Please open this in full screen</p>
<form class="w3-container">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border"/><br/>
<input type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black"/>
</form>
<p class="w3-padding w3-center w3-card-4">© Copyright 123456789. All rights Reserved.</p>
```